# Creating the same SignalR Hub for all the clients

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm just start testing SignalR for monitoring application . I have a control which make a call to the Hub by the client side. I noticed , each time the client make Connection.Hub.Start() it creates a new Hub instance in the server , I need to refresh my control all the time , so I don't want it to create new Hub for each one.

Is there a way to create single Hub for all clients or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A Hub instance is created for each request, much like an ASP.NET Page instance is created for each request in WebForms, a Controller is created for each request in ASP.NET MVC or a WCF service instance is created for each service request when using InstanceMode.PerCall.

If you want to maintain shared state between Hub requests/instances you would need to use a static field or some other, more advanced form of state sharing (e.g. dependency injected singleton).

Comment: Thanks , this is clear . In per call the server do the job of the request and finish. but here I have a situation it has to hold the clients connection to push them data , Otherwise how SinalR maintain all the conected clients , if each call has a new hub.

Comment: A Hub is an abstraction layer that sits above that lower level connectivity aspects of SignalR and presents requests to you in that simpler instance-per-request execution model. If you want to work at a lower layer then work with at the PersistentConnection class directly. Hubs and their methods are actually invoked via HubDispatcher which is a PersistentConnection subclass. It's a much more difficult layer to work at and that's why the Hubs abstraction exists in the first place.

Comment: can you show us sample code for not creating instance each time ?